# Interpretation of trace (.ad) file (without the involvement of TRACE32) [CPU Load]

Tags: debugging, embedded, trace, trace32, lauterbach

I'm trying to measure CPU load using TRACE32. I'm able to save the results as `.ad` files. But I need to reload them into the tool again to view. How to interpret `.ad` file (without the involvement of TRACE32)? I couldn't find any format for that file. If I could get a log out of it, it'd be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRACE32 `.ad` files are a proprietary file format, not intended to be loaded and interpreted by other tools. In order to interface with other tools, use the `Trace.EXPORT` command group to export the trace data.

In order to measure the CPU load, you can also use the measurement features buildt into TRACE32, like the `Trace.STATistic` commands.

Comment: Thanks... After a bit of research I was about to conclude the same. Thanks for confirming. I'll proceed with other ways of measuring CPU load